# Problem with adduser on new install

Tags: sudo, adduser

I am a noob trying to get an install of ubuntu 14.04 LTS up and running on a virtual server on linode.  I have not done much on it yet.  Earlier today I tried to add some users.  I was able to add one non-admin test user just fine.  I used the command

```
adduser testuser
```

I then wanted to add a test user with admin privileges.  I used the command

```
adduser testadminuser sudo
```

did not work.  comes back with the error

```
adduser: the user testadminuser does not exist.
```

It almost looks like no `sudo` groups exist.  I used a canned load by the hosting site: I would think it is set up for adding an admin user. I think it is a user error, but am stymied.

I did look at `/etc/groups`, and there is no `sudo` group.

Help!

Comment: Is there a `wheel` or `admin` group present? You can see which group has admin privileges by looking at `/etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The syntax:

```
adduser <username> <group>
```

is for adding an *existing* user to an *existing* group. So you will have to create the `testadminuser` before adding to any group:

```
adduser testadminuser
adduser testadminuser sudo
```

You can use the `useradd` command to combine both steps, but that is a bit more involved. Or, if you're OK with `sudo` being the primary group of `testadminuser` (as opposed to having a new user group created for that user's primary group), you can use the `--ingroup` option:

```
adduser --ingroup sudo testadminuser
```

Comment: Thanks @muru for this precise answer. Also after reading your suggestion, looking in /etc/sudoers on my 12.04 system the default group "admin" is for gaining root privileges while the default group "sudo" is more powerful and can execute any command. It should be similar on 14.04 and can easily be checked.

Comment: @GrantBowman true, but it seems OP is on some sort of shared hosting where the provider may have modified it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you (muru, grantbownam) for your answers.  You helped a noob get to the next step.

Comment: @J-Logger if the answer solved the problem, you can accept it by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: thanks agian... just did that.  says 1 answer, but has not changed it to green... ???

Comment: @J-Logger that's fine. Might be some temporary bug. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this it works on fresh new install on gcloud gcp Debian ubuntu.

```
# create a password for root on fresh installation

sudo passwd

# Now login to sudo user with the below command and create new user

su -l
adduser <new_user_name>

# Add created user to the sudo group with this below command

adduser <new_user_name> sudo
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hello. There is not such Linux distro as Debian Ubuntu. You have run the name of 2 different distros together.